# Where can I get VC++ 2005 redistributable version 8.0.50727.5592 including PDBs?

Tags: windows, visual-c++, debug-symbols, winsxs

Sometimes crash dump files of our customers will contain references to

```
mfc80u.dll  *C:\Windows\winsxs\x86_microsoft.vc80.mfc_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_8.0.50727.5592_none_cbf62b764709d1c9\mfc80u.dll  N/A N/A No matching binary found.       20  8.00.50727.5592 11.01.2011 07:32    6E860000-6E96F000   memory.dmp: Native  
msvcr80.dll *C:\Windows\winsxs\x86_microsoft.vc80.crt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_8.0.50727.5592_none_d09196c24426e2d4\msvcr80.dll N/A N/A No matching binary found.       21  8.00.50727.5592 11.01.2011 06:17    74E40000-74EDB000   memory.dmp: Native
```

The problem is, I don't get proper stack traces for these, because these DLLs ([from April, 2011](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2465367)) were superseded by a further patch [from June, 2011](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2538218) and [contrary to what I can find on the net](http://wiki.mcneel.com/developer/sdksamples/vcredist), the [download from MS](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=26347) does *not* contain the 5592 version, but only the 6195 version of the CRT/MFC/... DLLs.

Our executable's manifest points to version `8.0.50727.4053` but that doesn't help as this version is superseded by 5592 and later by 6195. The SxSTrace output goes like this: (just ignore the german text and look at the version numbers)

```
INFORMATION: Verweis "Microsoft.VC80.CRT,processorArchitecture="x86",publicKeyToken="1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b",type="win32",version="8.0.50727.4053"" wird aufgelöst.
...
    INFORMATION: Für ProcessorArchitecture "x86" wird der Verweis aufgelöst.
    INFORMATION: Für ProcessorArchitecture "x86" wird der Verweis aufgelöst.
        INFORMATION: Verweis für Kultur "Neutral" wird aufgelöst.
            INFORMATION: Bindungsrichtlinie wird angewendet.
                INFORMATION: Sucht nach Herausgeberrichtlinien in "C:\Windows\WinSxS\manifests\x86_policy.8.0.microsoft.vc80.crt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_8.0.50727.6195_none_517205a10f4550e3.manifest".
                INFORMATION: Die Assemblierungsversion wurde von der Herausgeberrichtlinie umgeleitet.
                INFORMATION: Die Bereitstellungsrichtlinien-Assemblierungsidentität ist Microsoft.VC80.CRT,processorArchitecture="x86",publicKeyToken="1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b",type="win32",version="8.0.50727.6195".
```

Now, maybe I'll be able to obtain the exact DLLs from the customer's PC, but that still leaves me with the DLLs only, and I still won't have any debug symbols (PDB files).

Since, looking at my dump (e.g. for kernel32), I can see that normally all system DLLs should be loaded from the MS symbol servers (or its cache) --

```
kernel32.dll    C:\WINDOWS\Symbols\Cache\kernel32.dll\4e211484100000\kernel32.dll   N/A N/A Symbols loaded (source information stripped).   C:\WINDOWS\Symbols\Cache\wkernel32.pdb\0EB73428EC4E430FB8EDD94C5946855B2\wkernel32.pdb  3   6.01.7600.16850 16.07.2011 05:33    76820000-76920000   memory.dmp: Native
```

<strike>I must assume that</strike> Microsoft <strike>purged the 5592 version of these files from their symbol server, thereby</strike> effectively preventing any useful debugging if a customer PC does include the April,2011 update but not the June,2011 update. From what I can infer from the MS pages, these updates are included in Windows Update, so there's really nothing I can do if a customer has an incomplete update mechanism.

Is there still a download from MS for the original patch that would include the 5592 DLL and PDB files?

---

Update: It would seem that the MS symbol server *does* contain the PDB file for the 5592 DLL verison, but it *does not* contain the DLL. (Now whether that makes sense is another question, but maybe that's the way it works with these DLLs.)

I could determine the following:

- PDB for 4053 : `...\Cache\msvcr80.i386.pdb\7D5669C7431445CD84D149AE19FE3CD51\msvcr80.i386.pdb`
- PDB for 5592 (because WinDbg does load that one) : `...\cache\msvcr80.i386.pdb\3FA5DD7B7FAF4F2EAC5ABEDC03012DB21\msvcr80.i386.pdb`
- PDB for 6195: `...Cache\msvcr80.i386.pdb\54C9E2F351544D1CB39517DC4B299EA81\msvcr80.i386.pdb`

Comment: Yes, that rings a bell, they flubbed that first update and quickly replaced it.  You will need to ask the client to install the latest update.  Pointing out that their current version is borken is an obvious motivator.

Comment: @HansPassant - Yeah, we'll point that out anyway. But oc it doesn't help me to analyze *this* dump. (And it's not like it was one of them reproducible ones, rather a random crash.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `pdb` files are all that is needed to analyze a (full) dump with **WinDbg** - the binaries are not needed for WinDbg, but the Visual Stuido (2005) debugger *does* seem to require the binaries.

So in this case do not use VS, but use WinDbg to analyze this particular dump.